# Doubts about one charaterization of the naturality on adjuntions

Tags: category-theory

I'm trying to prove the following lemma:

[image]

I've proved the $\Rightarrow$ direction, but I couldn't see how the bijection between the commutative squares induces naturality on the isomorphisms, namely to prove the $\Leftarrow$ direction. Could you give me some hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To go the other direction, we show that the adjunction is natural in $c$. Showing it is natural in $d$ is analogous.

Consider arbitrary arrows $g^\flat : C(c, Gd)$ and $h : C(a, c)$. We must show that $(g^\flat \circ h)^\sharp = g^\sharp \circ Fh$. To do this, we define $f^\flat = g^\flat \circ h$ and $k = 1_d$. Then we have $Gk \circ f^\flat = g^\flat \circ h$. Thus, we have $g^\sharp \circ Fh = k \circ f^\sharp = f^\sharp = (g^\flat \circ h)^\sharp$.